# SOAP message prefix issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, c#-4.0, soap

I have a **SOAP message** like following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:SaveMethod xmlns:ns1="urn:MyService" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <data xsi:type="xsd:string">
        <![CDATA[
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
        <test>123</test>
        ]]>
      </data>
    </ns1:SaveMethod>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My WCF is **working fine** when the SaveMethod tag is **without prefix** e.g.

```
<SaveMethod>
<data xsi:type="xsd:string">
etc.
```

But since i am *not able to edit* the **SOAP message** i need to find out how to make the SaveMethod accept the **tag with prefix ns1**.

Btw my method is as follows:

```
public void SaveMethod(String data){
   // do something
}
```

Maybe i can do something on the client-side (**HttpWebRequest** used btw) ??

Thank you very much

Comment: Try to specify the namespace in your interface contract using: [ServiceContract(Namespace = "MyService")]

Comment: Namespace = "MyService" or Namespace = "urn:MyService" ???

Comment: i tried with and without urn: but none of them worked. Do you have another ideas maybe?